# Having problems putting strings in a vector of strings?

Tags: c++, vector

Good night, 
I have two strings as parameters(campo e valor) and I want to put them in two separate vector, but is giving me strange errors and I cannot find why, I am new to C++ so it's probably a newbie mistake.

My class:

```
/* Includes */
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Geral {
private:
vector<string> v_campo;
vector<string> v_valor;
public:
 Geral();
 ~Geral();
 void TomaCampoValor(string campo, string valor);
 void Mostrar();
 string GetValorCampo(string campo);
 bool ExisteCampo(string campo);
};
```

This is my cpp:

```
 void Geral::TomaCampoValor(string _campo, string _valor) {
    int i = 0;

    // Searching if there is already the same _campo
    for (i = 0; i < v_campo.size(); i++) {
        if (v_campo[i].c_str() == _campo) {
            v_valor[i].push_back(*_valor.c_str());`
            return;
        }
    }

     // If doesn't find it
     v_campo[i].push_back(*_campo.c_str());
     v_valor[i].push_back(*_valor.c_str());
    }
```

This is the error that is giving me
[Error that is giving me:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6or4.png)

Thanks in advance, if I didn't make my self clear pleasy ask.

Comment: Prefer to pass non-POD types by reference, or const reference if they won't be modified.  This prevents the compiler from making a copy of the `std::string` and passing to your function.

Comment: The error you are getting is that the vector is out of range. You should review your code, then read more about why is this happening and finally ask questions here showing your work. Use the following as a hint: what happens when you don't initialize the vector?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Thomas, I used to use it on C I can't forget to use it on C++.

Comment: @Cabrra Thanks. I am used to C where I need to do everything so having all of this amazing functions all at my disposal is awesome. And there is so much more different ways to do the same thing in C++ that I lose myself trying to find what I want

Comment: Your out of range is probably caused by 2 push_backs outside of the loop as `i` will be last index + 1 after the loop

Answer (score 0):

surprised this even compiles

you mean

```
 v_campo.push_back(_campo);
 v_valor.push_back(_valor);
```

EDIT:

this is wrong too

```
(v_campo[i].c_str() == _campo)
```

you mean

```
(v_campo[i] == _campo)
```

Make sure you do not ignore compiler warnings, they are there to help you

Comment: Thank you for your help ! 
Now it works, but I wanted to do an array (v_campo) where I will put all the camps, and then for each camp I wanted to do an array of values. Is that possible ? I can't seem to find the answer

Comment: you are using vector instead of array, vector is much better. Why do you want to change to array?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say vector(i am used to say array bad habit) but it’s possible what I ask pm100 ?

Comment: you should have a map of campo to list value (std::map<string,list<string>>)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Since `_valor` is a `std::string` type, there is no need to create a `std::string` from the `c_str()` method.

Try this:

```
v_campo.push_back(_campo);
v_valor.push_back(_valor);
```

Another issue is that `v_campo[i]` is a `std::string` type and `std::string` doesn't have a `push_back` method for strings.

Comment: So in order for me to search if there is already a _camp in vector, should I use an iterator ?

Comment: Yes, because `std::find` returns an iterator. :-)

Comment: If you want to loop through the vector, you don't need an iterator; an index will work.  For example:  `for (size_t i = 0; i < v_campo.size(); ++i) { if (v_campo[i] == "Mario") break; }`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, will try it out !

Comment: What do you mean by `std::string` not having `push_back` method? https://ideone.com/Rt9mNe

Comment: @KillzoneKid:  There isn't a method for `push_back(char *)`.

Comment: There isn’t, but why is it relevant? They are pushing dereferenced pointer which is a `char`

Answer (score 0):

So, based on your approach to the problem and further questions I guess you need to create some sort of database for camps and their features of some sort which you want to link with respective camps.
You could start with the following approach:

- Look for more optimized data structure to hold your data, since you want to get something like this { "Camp1" : feature_array1, "Camp2" : feature_array2 } (Few hints: key-value pairs and very quick inserting and finding items)
- Try to call constructors on non-POD types, it can prevent some bugs or could help you compile the program.
- Look into const reference arguments, it could be helpful.
- `std::string` isn't equal to C-style char* strings, since it doesn't have \0 in the end, so your equality test is useless.
- Check out pros and cons of `using namespace std`

Comment: Thank you Pavlo, I ll take a look at all this points. I was searching a bit and I think I ll use a map to solve my problem. Thanks once again !

Comment: @diogofalkendiogofalken Sure thing, you could also look at the ways of adding items to map. std::map::insert vs mapname[keyname]

Comment: I will thanks for your help, that will save my project that I have to do until Friday !